# Can we achieve features like no message loss and no crash when we use log4cplu as client and rsyslog as server

Tags: rsyslog, log4cplus

We are planning to use log4cplus as client with syslog appender feature and using rsyslog as server ( both local system). I am not clear with syslog appender of log4cplus features. I would like to know if stack overflow, crash are avoidable or I will still face all the inherent issues of vanilla syslog as client API(log4cplus) are still using glibc's  syslog function ?

1. Can I put some filters to drop non-criticial ( INFO, debug) messages at client side rather than sending it to rsyslog and getting dropped there?
2. what all measures are taken care at log4cplus client side to avoid crash in case of deadlock etc. ?

Looking forward for resolution of all my above doubt or any doc which can clear all my doubts?

Answer (score 0):

Log4cplus is just ordinary C++ library. It does nothing magical to prevent message loss on stack overflow or any other kind of fatal condition.

Ad 1, to filter out less important messages you can use `Threshold` property on appender in your configuration file.

Ad 2, what deadlock and what etc.?